# What is the difference between an application server and php/java plus webserver?

Tags: java, apache-http-server, php, jboss

Im having a hard time getting this terminology straight.

What exactly does one mean by application server? To me it seems like a webserver with added scripting capabilities like a AMP-server or Apache + JSP.

When I look at the documentation of for example JBoss or Zend, it looks like it only runs the servlet/script when it receives a http-request. Same as the php-interpreter in an AMP setup. And the network traffic is also only through http-requests.

The difference I have noticed is the the application servers seems to have a better controll over the currently running scripts/servlets.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936197/what-is-the-difference-between-application-server-and-web-server

Answer (score 1):

JEE artifacts such as JSP/ servlets / EJB run in a container.
JEE defines strict guidelines on what a container is and how it is supposed to behave.

For example tomcat is a servlet container. servlet container or for that matter any container provides for respective artifacts to run.

Tomcat is only servlet container. it has the capability to run servlets.

Application server is more than just a container. Application server has EJB container, JMS service provider, data source provider, JNDI service provider and others.
all these combined makes an application server.

Apache can not run JSP/ Servlets. Tomcat can. Apache + tomcat combination is used at several places as Apache is used for serving static content.

Comment: One of the worst answers i have seen. Explain things by function not names and brands. Nothing is relevant here. You just throw in names of technology products which might or might not have anything to do with application servers or how php works.